# package com.felees.hbnpojogen.persistence does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

I cant find this package anywhere.
package com.felees.hbnpojogen.persistence does not exist.
Has anybody come across it?

The error came up when I tried to build a new CVS repository. In the pom.xml there is a dependency

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.felees</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbnpojogen</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

.

Comment: Last time I've seen it on the bus station, who knows where it is now... Can you be more specific? Where do you get this error?

Comment: Next time, post your question specifically. And try to find answer by yourself by doing some research, don't blindly post your questions here without doing any research about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the package [here](http://en.sourceforge.jp/frs/g_redir.php?m=ncu&f=/hibernatepojoge/hibernatepojoge/hbnpojogen/hbnpojogen-persistence-1.4.4.jar)

Comment: Turns out this is what I had to do.
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=libs\hbnpojogen-persistence-1.4.4.jar -DgroupId=com.felees -DartifactId=hbnpojogen -Dversion=1.4.4 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: @precursor, well I have not worked on maven much, i just helped you to get the package u needed :) good that u figured out the problem.